# Vim not rendering text when moving up

Tags: terminal, scrolling, original-vim, redraw, st

I can move down until the last line of a file with no issues. However, when move up the text that was out of screen bounds does not render (as shown by the figure) until i press `Ctrl + L` to force rendering.
[image: Text not rendered]

My terminal is st.
This is my .vimrc

```
" All system-wide defaults are set in $VIMRUNTIME/archlinux.vim (usually just
" /usr/share/vim/vimfiles/archlinux.vim) and sourced by the call to :runtime
" you can find below.  If you wish to change any of those settings, you should
" do it in this file (/etc/vimrc), since archlinux.vim will be overwritten
" everytime an upgrade of the vim packages is performed.  It is recommended to
" make changes after sourcing archlinux.vim since it alters the value of the
" 'compatible' option.

" Disable Background Color Erase (BCE) so that color schemes
" render properly when inside 256-color tmux and GNU screen.
if &term =~ '256color'
    set t_ut=
endif

" This line should not be removed as it ensures that various options are
" properly set to work with the Vim-related packages.
runtime! archlinux.vim

" If you prefer the old-style vim functionalty, add 'runtime! vimrc_example.vim'
" Or better yet, read /usr/share/vim/vim80/vimrc_example.vim or the vim manual
" and configure vim to your own liking!

" do not load defaults if ~/.vimrc is missing
"let skip_defaults_vim=1

" adding my configs
:set lazyredraw 
:set history=500
:set number
:set mouse=a
:set clipboard+=unnamed  " use the clipboards of vim and win
:set paste               " Paste from a windows or from vim
:set go+=a               " Visual selection automatically copied to the clipboard
:set laststatus=2

" now this is configurations for plugins

if empty(glob('~/.vim/autoload/plug.vim'))
  silent !curl -fLo ~/.vim/autoload/plug.vim --create-dirs
    \ https://raw.githubusercontent.com/junegunn/vim-plug/master/plug.vim
  autocmd VimEnter * PlugInstall --sync | source $MYVIMRC
endif

" Specify a directory for plugins
" - For Neovim: stdpath('data') . '/plugged'
" - Avoid using standard Vim directory names like 'plugin'
call plug#begin('~/.vim/plugged')

Plug 'itchyny/lightline.vim'

" Initialize plugin system
call plug#end()
```

Comment: Welcome to Vi and Vim! Does this get fixed if you remove the `set t_ut=` line from your vimrc? It looks suspicious... What's your `$TERM` setting in the shell? Outside tmux? And inside tmux? You can also try to see whether removing `set lazyredraw` will improve it, but it might just make scrolling slower, so I'd check it mostly as "yeah, that fixes it but makes Vim less usable..."

Comment: removing `set t_ut=` and `set lazyredraw` do not help, even with the default `.vimrc` file i have the same problem. In TTY i do not have this issue. My `$TERM` is `st-256color`.

Comment: Did you apply any patches to `st`, or are you using the standard version?

Comment: Indeed the patching was the problem. I just repatched everything and now it works as it should! Many thanks for your help.